# How to increase quota effictevly on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We often try to increase quota and we hit the limits eg.:

1. (us-central)  increasing cpu limits from 1600 -> 2500, rejected because "We attempted to adjust the quota for your project: flyways but did not find any changes that needed to be made. This could be due to being unable to fulfill part of the request"
2. (us-east) cpu limits 70 -> 500, rejected: "Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this time"
3. (us-central) C2 limits 24 -> 100, rejected: "We attempted to adjust the quota for your project: "XXX" but did not find any changes that needed to be made. This could be due to being unable to fulfill part of the request"

Is there any way that we can push forward our quotas, call someone or chat with someone or has high current usage?

Comment: You will need to open a support ticket with Google. This requires a support subscription. https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue is best addressed by Google support directly.